# Understanding while loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm having trouble with a question my professor gave me. I don't need the answer I just need something to go off of. The question is:

> Use a `while` loop to find the smallest number `N` for which the sum of the integers `1` through `N` is larger than `999`

Here's what I have so far, been working for a few hours and can't find anything on it.

```
sum=0;
while sum>999
    sum=1+n
    disp('sum is', sum)
    disp('n=',n)
end
```

Comment: I suggest that you pause and take some time to read up on Matlab programming. Then, read the documentation on [`while`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) and try the examples. Finally, consider how `n` and `sum` need to change in your loop. You should also look at your `while` condition and understand what happens if `sum` is set to `0` right before.

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name, as it's a [built-in function](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html). Overshadowing this with your variable can get you into trouble if you want to use the *function*  `sum` later in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exit your while loop when `sum_val > 999`. If you look at your exit condition and read it as words, you can see your problem:

> `while sum_val > 999` is "Loop and perform loop statements while the value of sum is **greater** than 999".

Since your sum starts at 0, you will never enter your loop, because sum is less than 999. You want:

> "Loop and perform loop statements while the value of sum is **less** than 999"

which is:

```
while sum_val < 999
```

As well as this you don't define your counter `n`. You do this:

```
sum_val=1+n
```

When you count your sum, you need to ensure that you are actually summing the right things. What is `sum` it is the previous value of `sum` added with the current value of `n`. So do that:

```
sum_val = sum_val + n
```

Also what is `n`? Well as in the problem statement, `n` counts from 1 to `N` (your eventual goal). So you need to make sure you update that (and set it).

```
n = 1
...
n = n+1
```

Finally, sum is a function name, so you cant use it. Use something else, like `sum_val` as shown above.

You will need to sort out where in the code these should go.

Comment: Fantastic Mr Fox's answer is correct. For the future, I would recommend [debugging](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) the problem. This way you will be able to solve the issue yourself and most probably in less time.